# how to get group chat history from xmpp server php

Tags: php, xmpp, openfire, groupchat, jaxl

I need to get group chat history from **Openfire** with **JAXL** library.

I am using JAXL library for open fire connection and chat purpose, but it doesn't get me the  group chat history, when user is login at a time other user send message than that message is received but history didn't retrieved.

Please check the link below, it's my output link

https://www.screencast.com/t/P4LxVPqXNS2

I tried Googling it but it didn't gave me the satisfactory Answer.

Any idea will be great help.

Comment: Its possible with candy JS library. github.com/candy-chat/candy